# JQuery droppable functionality doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I want to create an application that drops certain elements on other elements, using jquery library. The draggable feature seems to be working, but the droppable feature doesn't work. I tried to assign id to draggable and droppable, because it solved someone's problem (the solution for that person's problem was to change the library(the problem was the library)), which is similar to mine. I used jquery library and js (modified js embeded in the html document with it's code listed bellow) from here: http://superdit.com/2011/04/02/drag-drop-shopping-cart-using-jquery/. I would say again that everything works except the droppable feature.

Any help would be great! Thank you!

(Below is the html code (which includes js) and the css):

```
<html>
```

Repartiţia electronilor pe orbitali, straturi şi substraturi pentru primele 36 de elemente

```
//superfunctia
function activateApp() {
    var infoSelected = document.getElementById("option_selected_text");
    var element= new Array();

    element[0]="";
    element[1] = "Hidrogen";
    element[2] = "Heliu";
    element[3] = "Litiu";
    element[4] = "Beriliu";
    element[5] = "Bor";
    element[6] = "Carbon";
    element[7] = "Azot";
    element[8] = "Oxigen";
    element[9] = "Fluor";
    element[10] = "Neon";
    element[11] = "Sodiu";
    element[12] = "Magneziu";
    element[13] = "Aluminiu";
    element[14] = "Siliciu";
    element[15] = "Fosfor";
    element[16] = "Sulf";
    element[17] = "Clor";
    element[18] = "Argon";
    element[19] = "Potasiu";
    element[20] = "Calciu";
    element[21] = "Scandiu";
    element[22] = "Titan";
    element[23] = "Vanadiu";
    element[24] = "Crom";
    element[25] = "Mangan";
    element[26] = "Fier";
    element[27] = "Cobalt";
    element[28] = "Nichel";
    element[29] = "Cupru";
    element[30] = "Zinc";
    element[31] = "Galiu";
    element[32] = "Germaniu";       
    element[33] = "Arsen";
    element[34] = "Seleniu";
    element[35] = "Brom";
    element[36] = "Kripton";


    var simbol = new Array();

    simbol[0] = "";
    simbol[1] = "H";
    simbol[2] = "He ";
    simbol[3] = "Li";
    simbol[4] = "Be";
    simbol[5] = "B";
    simbol[6] = "C";
    simbol[7] = "N";
    simbol[8] = "O";
    simbol[9] = "F";
    simbol[10] = "Ne";
    simbol[11] = "Na";
    simbol[12] = "Mg";
    simbol[13] = "Al";
    simbol[14] = "Si";
    simbol[15] = "P";
    simbol[16] = "S";
    simbol[17] = "Cl";
    simbol[18] = "Ar";
    simbol[19] = "K";
    simbol[20] = "Ca";
    simbol[21] = "Sc";
    simbol[22] = "Ti";
    simbol[23] = "V";
    simbol[24] = "Cr";
    simbol[25] = "Mn";
    simbol[26] = "Fe";
    simbol[27] = "Co";
    simbol[28] = "Ni";
    simbol[29] = "cu";
    simbol[30] = "Zn";
    simbol[31] = "Ga";
    simbol[32] = "Ge";      
    simbol[33] = "As";
    simbol[34] = "se";
    simbol[35] = "Br";
    simbol[36] = "Kr";


infoSelected.innerHTML = "Element: "+"<i>"+element[val.value]+"</i>"+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+"Simbol: "+"<i>"+simbol[val.value]+"</i>";
$( ".electron_1" ).draggable({
    revert: true    
});
$( ".electron_2" ).draggable({
    revert: true    
}); 
$("#up_spin").droppable({
    accept: ".electron_1",
    activeClass: "drop-active",
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    drop: function(event,ui) {
        var elect1 = ui.draggable.html();
        var upid = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        var html = '<div class="electron1 up_dropped">';
            html = html + '<div class="delete_mark">';
            html = html + '<a onclick="remove(this)" class="remove '+upid+'">&times;</a>';
                html = html + elect1+'</div>';
                $("#up_spin").append(html);
    }
});

$("#down_spin").droppable({
    accept: ".electron_2",
    activeClass: "drop-active",
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    drop: function(event,ui) {
        var elect2 = ui.draggable.html();
        var downid = ui.draggable.attr("id");
        var html = '<div class="down_spin up_dropped">';
                html = html + '<div class="delete_mark">';
                html = html + '<a onclick="remove(this)" class="remove '+downupid+'">&times;</a>';
                html = html + '<div/>'+elect2+'</div>';
                $(".down_spin").append(html);
    }
});




}
</script>
```

```
<div id="main">

  <a href="repartitie.html">Cum se repartizeaz&#259; electronii pe orbitali, straturi &#351;i substraturi </a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
  <a href="lectie.html"> Structura &#238;nveli&#351;ului electronic </a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="help.html"> Help(?) </a> 

</div>


<div id="config_container">
 <div id="axis">
    <img src="images/axis.png">
 </div>



 <div id="orbital_container">
<div id="orbital_content">
<div class="orbital_label"> 4p </div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="orbital_content">
<div class="orbital_label"> 3d </div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="orbital_content">
<div class="orbital_label"> 4s </div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

</div>


<div id="orbital_content">
<div class="orbital_label"> 3p </div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

</div>


<div id="orbital_content">
<div class="orbital_label"> 3s </div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="orbital_content">
<div class="orbital_label"> 2p </div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="orbital_content">
<div class="orbital_label"> 2s </div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="orbital_content">
<div class="orbital_label"> 1s </div>

<div class="electron_pear">
<div id="up_spin"></div>
<div id="down_spin"></div>
</div>

</div>

 </div>
 </div>

 <div id="control_container">
 <div id="settings_container">
 <div id="settings_content">
 <div class="z_text"> Z = </div>  
 <select id="val" name="val">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
<option value="32">32</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
<option value="34">34</option>
<option value="35">35</option>
<option value="36">36</option>
 </select>
 <div class="electron_1"></div>
 <div class="electron_2"></div>
 <a href="javascript: void(0)" ><input type="button" name="Submit" value="Start" class="confirmed" onclick="activateApp();"/></a>
 <a href="javascript: void(0)" ><input type="button" name="Submit" value="Resetare" class="erase" onclick="checkForm();"/> </a> 


 </div>

 <div id="settings_content" style="margin-top: 15px;">
<div id="option_selected_text"></div>

 </div>
```

```
// CSS


body {
    font-family: Arial, "Free Sans";
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
#main {
//  position: fixed;
    background: #25bcde;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 2px 0 6px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #118090;
}
#main a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#main a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


#config_container {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#axis {
//  margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}


.confirmed {
    display: inline;
//  position: absolute;
    background: #25bcde;
    width: 120px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border: 2px solid #25bcde;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    z-index: 9;
}

a:hover *.confirmed {
    font-style: italic;
}

.erase {
    display: inline;
//  position: absolute;
    background: #25bcde;
    width: 100px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border: 2px solid #25bcde;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    z-index: 9;
}

a:hover *.erase {
    font-style: italic;
}

#orbital_container {
    display: block;
//  position: relative;
    width: 670px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 12px;
//  margin-bottom: 10px;
//  clear: right;
}

#orbital_content {
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.orbital_label {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    color: #6099cc;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-right: 14px;
}

.electron_pear {
    display: inline;    
}

#up_spin {
    background: #ef7812;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
//  padding: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    z-index: 0;
}

#down_spin {
    background: #ef7812;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
//  padding: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    z-index: 0;
}

#control_container {
//  position: relative;
//  display: inline;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
//  text-align: center;
}

#settings_container {
    display: block;
//  position: relative;
}

#settings_content {
    display: table; 
}

.z_text {
    display: inline;
//  position: absolute;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;

}

#val {
    display: inline;
//  position: absolute;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
//  font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 0;
}

.electron_1 {
    background-color: #ef7812;
    background-image: url('images/arrow-up.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom; 
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    float: left;
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
//  font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
}

.electron_2 {
    background-color: #ef7812;
    background-image: url('images/arrow-down.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    float: left;
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
//  font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 5;
}

#option_selected_text {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 480px;
    height: 16px;
    float: left;
//  text-align: left;   
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3e3e3e;
}

.drop-active {
    background-color: #68bf32;
}

.drop-hover {
    background-color: #32bf32;
}

.up_dropped {
    cursor: default;
}

.delete_mark {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to duplicate the problem you're having with a small demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are inconsistencies between your two draggable handlers, in the last line for the second one you use a class selector ".down_spin", where everywhere else you used id selector "#down_spin".

The other big problem is that no two DOM elements should have the same id in your document, try changing all **up_spin** and **down_spin** elements to have a class by those names and change your id selectors to class selectors. Make sure you make up your mind wether you want to use classes or ids by the above rules, as you use id in your static markup, but classes in your droppable handler's html injection.

Also in your down_spin draggable handler remove the **''** bit from your html string concatenation, you haven't got it in the up_spin handler, and it's not right anyway.

And if you're using jQuery, it's best to be consistent and use it everywhere, change:

```
infoSelected.innerHTML = "Element: "+"<i>"+element[val.value]+"</i>"+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+"Simbol: "+"<i>"+simbol[val.value]+"</i>";
```

to:

```
$(infoSelected).html("Element: "+"<i>"+element[val.value]+"</i>"+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+"Simbol: "+"<i>"+simbol[val.value]+"</i>");
```

After all these clean-ups, it might just magically start working.

Comment: Thank you very much, DarthJDG! I made all the changes you suggested. Now, it works!